# Conditional expectation and measurable transformations

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables such that $f$ is the joint density of $(X,Y)$.

If $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)dx>0$ for every $y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $g$ is a measurable function such that $E\lvert g(X)\rvert<\infty$, one can easily check that
\begin{equation}
E(g(X)\mid Y)=h(Y)
\end{equation}
where $h(y):=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)f(x,y)\,dx/\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)\,dx$. According to [Rick Durrett's book](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf) we can get rid of the hypothesis of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)\,dx$ being strictly positive just by defining $h$ as we please when $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)\,dx=0$, but I have been struggling to prove this without success. Any idea?

Just in case it helps, I leave here the proof of the easy part:

It is clear that $h(Y)\in\sigma(Y)$, then, Let $A\in\sigma(Y)$, so $A=Y^{-1}(B)$, being $B\subset\mathbb{R}$ some borelian set.
\begin{equation}
\int_Ah(Y)=\int_Bh(y)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy=\int_B\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)f(x,y)\,dx\,dy
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\int_Ag(X)=\int_\Omega g(X)1_A=\int_{\Omega}j(X,Y)=\int_{B}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)f(x,y)\,dx\,dy
\end{equation}

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like the main issue is verifying the two equations for $\int_A h(Y)$, after modifying $h$ on the values of $y$ for which $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) \, dx = 0$. Actually, your original calculation still works in this case. The first equation works as before, because $Y$ has density $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) \, dx$. The second equation still works, because (1) if $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) \, dx$ is positive then you obtain the integral involving $g$, and (2) if it is zero then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) \, f(x,y) \, dx$ is also zero.

Comment: @nahp why $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)f(x,y)dx$ is also $0$?

Comment: As a joint density, $f$ is nonnegative. If for a fixed $y$ we have $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) \, dx = 0$, this means that the function $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ is zero for almost-every $x$. Then $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) \, f(x,y) \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) \cdot 0 \, dx = 0.$$

Comment: @nahp Thanks, you're right! Miss that detail at first!